# Handling date objects javascript vs java

Tags: javascript, java

I have an date input field. The user inputs a date then submits and this date is saved in the database. I have two options on how to do things and I know how to implement both but I'm not too sure what the best practice is as I'm a noob.

Option 1: Take the value read from the date input which is a string and send that to my Spring back-end and then create a date object.

Option 2: Take the value read from the date input and create a Date object in JavaScript and send a date object to my spring controller.

I'm leaning towards option 1 because I'm thinking I will have better error handling in my controller?

Comment: Just an FYI, any value sent via HTTP request body (or query string) will be a **string**. You cannot post a JS `Date` instance to your backend without serialising it

Comment: IMO, the best serialisation format for dates is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). JS dates can use [`Date.prototype.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) to produce one of these

Comment: Getting the customer input and turning it into a JS Date object, can be used as a frontend validation method on the input. Yet, what will the backend receive will be a string representation of the object.

Comment: @Phil I didn't know that, thank you! Also I tried option 2 and it worked fine without me serializing it. Maybe it serialized it automatically when you specify what type your backend is expecting?

Comment: @DaveDaBest if you are sending JSON, `Date.prototype.toJSON()` internally calls `toISOString()`

Comment: @Phil makes sense! do you see any problems with option 1?

Comment: Handling dates in HTML forms is notoriously difficult due to mixed browser support for `<input type="date">` / `<input type="datetime-local">`. This question is a little too broad to answer canonically. Perhaps you could add some detail about how you're generating dates in your frontend and getting them to your backend. For instance, option #2 is great if your dates are generated and posted via JS / AJAX

Comment: @Phil I didn't think I needed to post code, sorry about that. So I'm generating the input like follows: `<input id="date" type="date">`. Reading it's value as follows: `$('date').val();` and using jQuery post to send the data via Ajax (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). Please le me know if you have more questions

Answer (score 1):

Your Question is moot as you will be sending a string of a date back to the server either way.

## ISO 8601

Generally best to use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats when exchanging date-time values as text. For a date that would be YYYY-MM-DD.

## *java.time*

As for performing date-time related work on that date value, I recommend using Java for that. Java offers the industry-leading date-time framework found in the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes, defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

The *java.time* classes conveniently use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when parsing/generating date-time strings.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2019-01-23" ) ;  // Parses standard ISO 8601 strings.
String output = ld.toString() ;                   // Generates "2019-01-23".
```